# How to import file using dynamic path on Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, import, angular6

I need to import file from path, which I get from variable's value. So it looks like this:

```
let test = require(configurationUrl);
```

where `configurationUrl` is some path like `'../../assets/app.conf.json'`.
So when I run the app I get this error:

> core.js:1601 ERROR Error: Cannot find module "../../assets/app.conf.json".

But when I write it like this:

```
let test = require("../../assets/app.conf.json");
```

there is no error.

I have found this problem on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3306), but haven't find solution yet.

Also I know that I can solve this issue like that:

```
loadConfigurationFromApi(configurationUrl: string) {

    this.http.get(configurationUrl).subscribe(
      res => {
        let test = res;
      })  
 }
```

But this way doesn't fit me.

Comment: What's you're looking for is called "dynamic import". If you search for it, you'll find your answers. https://netbasal.com/using-typescript-dynamic-imports-in-angular-d210547484dd https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-tips-dynamic-module-imports-with-the-angular-cli https://blog.angularindepth.com/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28

Comment: No, it can be called dynamic import by dynamic path. Thanks for your answer, but I already know how to dynamically import smth, the thing that bothers me how to store path in variable and use variable to import file.

Comment: "how to store path in variable" -- with `const path = 'xxx'`?

Comment: yes. when 
const path = './(some path)';
and then
const data = require(path);

Comment: @LazarLjubenović This dynamic import is working but as you can check when you set a string (path to module) as variable, you will see the error.
In this case @NazarTolmachov can not use predefined string, as it comes from environment. So the problem here - not dynamic import, but import with pat as variable like: `const path = 'some/path'; import(path).then()

Comment: Here is a [comment] (http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html#comment-3311608562) of another guy.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `require()` syntax directly since TypeScript by default use the new es2015 syntax.

So you'll need to use something like the following:

`import * as test from '../../assets/app.conf.json';`

Comment: You can use require, if you declare it.